# Google Maps Polyline Arrow not clickable if poiting to itself

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I am working on an application which plots several polylines across a map, normally from A to B, but sometimes also "from A to A", so to itself. In that case, only an Arrow to is shown, like this:
[image]

The problem now is that I am binding `infoWindows` to these polylines, so you when clicked a window popups up, which works well for the regular polylines, however for the arrow shown in the image, it doesn't work. It is simply not clickable.

I am creating the polylines like this:

```
var directionArrow = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW
};
// In this example, it's a line to itself
var pathCoordinates = [ 
    {lat: 40.76590936, lng: -73.97634151},
    {lat: 40.76590936, lng: -73.97634151} 
];

var path = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: pathCoordinates, 
    clickable: true,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: strokeWeightValue,
    icons: [{
        icon: directionArrow,
        offset: '100%'
    }]
});
```

Furthermore, every line gets a 'click' event with an infowindow bound to it:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(element, 'click', function(event) {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                infowindow.open(map);
})
```

Question: Is there a way around this? It seems like only the line is clickable but not the arrow.

Comment: How can we say there is a way around it if we cant see any code?

Comment: @John I have now.

Comment: do you have a  jsfiddle example handy?